# Running a local dev IPFS gateway that supports HTTPS

Tags: node.js, reverse-proxy, ipfs

I'm building a distributed web app designed to be hosted on IPFS. I want to do development in a web browser, using my local gateway to serve my files, but I use Javascript APIs that are not permitted without being served off HTTPS.

I tried starting a reverse proxy with self-signed ssl pointing at my local IPFS http gateway, but when I visit links using the reverse proxy, say `https://___hashhere___.ipfs.localhost:8081/`, I'm redirected to `http://___hashhere___.ipfs.localhost:8080/`:

```
GATEWAY_PORT=$(ipfs config Addresses.Gateway | cut -d'/' -f 5)
HTTPS_PORT=$((GATEWAY_PORT+1))

echo "https proxy to your ipfs gateway now at: https://localhost:$HTTPS_PORT"
exec npx local-ssl-proxy --source $HTTPS_PORT --target $GATEWAY_PORT
```

How can I run a local https+ipfs gateway in a command or two? I guess I need a reverse proxy that rewrites URLs in responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you use Chromium-based browser, then `http://___hashhere___.ipfs.localhost:8080/` will have `window.isSecureContext` set to `true` and you will have access to all Web APIs. No need for TLS setup for dev on localhost with Chromium (Firefox has a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1220810)).
- If you are running IPFS Companion, you may want to disable it when you develop your app, to ensure requests for IPFS resources are not redirected to the gateway set in browser extension's Preferences.
- In production, you deploy go-ipfs behind a reverse proxy and that proxy terminates TLS. You can control the  protocol scheme and host used in some of redirects via `X-Forwarded-Proto` and `X-Forwarded-Host` headers, as noted  in [go-ipfs/docs/config.md](https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/blob/master/docs/config.md#gateway-recipes)

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! I did indeed have IFPS companion enabled, and that was causing problems. Is the rule of thumb that all localhost domains will have window.isSecureContext='true'?

Comment: It is true for all Chromium-based browsers, and I would expect other browser vendors to implement binding localhost to loopback device ([rfc6761](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761#section-6.3)) at some point, if they don't already (prerequisite for secure context).